# Spring: Config API using ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have some APIs like this: `api/{id}/action/{action}` and want to add them to security.

```
@Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "api/*/action/*").access("hasAnyRole('View_account','Search_account')");
}
```

when I use the account without role: View_account and Search_account. This API still works well not response 403. Please advise me how to config security with multiple path variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use regexp for path variables:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "api/{\\d+}/action/**")
    .access("hasAnyRole('View_account','Search_account')");
}
```

In this case `{\\d+}` means that your id is digit

Comment: try this {\\w+}